# I am getting internal server error page on uploading symfony project on live server

Tags: php, symfony1

I am getting internal server error page on uploading symfony project on live server

I have just upload it and trying to run it on browser few keypoints to not:-

There is a databse file in it which is getting used in it
Upload this folder according to following folder structure

www.domainname.com/symfony_folder_name

Please let me know do i need to change any settings in it to run the project.

Comment: check the webserver's error log on the live server. it will tell you what caused the error.

Comment: [Sat Oct 18 14:22:00 2014] [alert] [client 122.163.207.64] /home3/stickcan/public_html/symfony_folder_name/web/.htaccess: LoadModule not allowed here, referer: http://stickcanvas.com/rrquiz_test/, this is the error what does that mean

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=LoadModule+not+allowed+here

Comment: [Sat Oct 18 15:50:44 2014] [error] [client 122.163.207.64] SoftException in Application.cpp:641: Could not execute script "/home3/stickcan/public_html/rrquiz_live/web/index.php", referer: http://stickcanvas.com/rrquiz_live/, i am getting this error now